# How to setup in GDAL 1.9.2 CPP project on windows VS C++?

Tags: c++, gdal

I recently downloaded GDAL source code from [here](http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/gdal-1.9.2.tar.gz)

I want to compile it and I want to modify it. So I started with its source code which I have downloaded.

Now I have seen that in supported compilers there is Visual C++ [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/SupportedCompiler)...

How to setup it?

**EDIT:**

I have successfully setup it but now i am looking for some options to run GDALDEM.cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Setup, I did it... just sharing so someone can save time

**Step 1** Download this Project from [here](http://vterrain.org/dist/gdal180_projects_vc9.zip)

This project is just project file. You need to copy GDAL source code to it in next steps..

**Step 2** Extract it.

**Step 3** Now copy paste all folders/files from gdal-1.11.1 folder to project solution folder

Select all files as shown below, press Ctrl +C

[image: copy this files]

Now paste in extracted project

[image: paste here]

**Step 4** Now open Visual C++ -> Open Project -> Select Project

[image: proj]

**Step 5** Simple Setup done....

[image: gdal setup done]

Answer (score 1):

You can get Visual C++ by downloading the free version of Visual Studio from Microsoft. Follow the link you have supplied, and go to the downloads section.
Once it's installed you should be able to read the help to see how to open and compile your project.